pdfpages for RTL documents
Sample RTL document:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import, main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{ScheherazadeNew}
\begin{document}

قِفَا نَبْكِ مِنْ ذِكْرَى حَبِيبٍ ومَنْزِلِ، بِسِقْطِ اللِّوَى بَيْنَ الدَّخُول فَحَوْمَلِ. فَتُوْضِحَ فَالمِقْراةِ لمْ يَعْفُ
رَسْمُها، لِمَا نَسَجَتْهَا مِنْ جَنُوبٍ وشَمْألِ. تَرَى بَعَرَ الأرْآمِ فِي عَرَصَاتِهَا، وَقِيْعَانِهَا كَأنَّهُ حَبُّ
فُلْفُلِ. كَأنِّي غَدَاةَ البَيْنِ يَوْمَ تَحَمَّلُوا، لَدَى سَمُرَاتِ الحَيِّ نَاقِفُ حَنْظَلِ. وُقُوْفًا بِهَا صَحْبِي عَليَّ
مَطِيَّهُمُ، يَقُوْلُوْنَ: لا تَهْلِكْ أَسًى وَتَجَمَّلِ. وإِنَّ شِفائِيَ عَبْرَةٌ مُهْرَاقَةٌ، فَهَلْ عِنْدَ رَسْمٍ دَارِسٍ مِنْ
مُعَوَّلِ؟. كَدَأْبِكَ مِنْ أُمِّ الحُوَيْرِثِ قَبْلَهَا، وَجَارَتِهَا أُمِّ الرَّبَابِ بِمَأْسَلِ. إِذَا قَامَتَا تَضَوَّعَ المِسْكُ
مِنْهُمَا، نَسِيْمَ الصَّبَا جَاءَتْ بِرَيَّا القَرَنْفُلِ. فَفَاضَتْ دُمُوْعُ العَيْنِ مِنِّي صَبَابَةً، عَلَى النَّحْرِ حَتَّى
بَلَّ دَمْعِيَ مِحْمَلِي.

\pagebreak
% ...
% and so on... repeated to generated multiple pages.

\end{document}


Then
$ pdfjam "rtl.pdf" \
    --landscape \
    --frame true \
    --nup 2x1 \
    --twoside

The result is:
---------
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
---------

where as it should be
---------
| 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 |
---------

As there is currently no option for RTL support in pdfpages, I'm looking for a script to fix this.
A workaround for this particular --nup 2x1 is to pass the document in a script that reshuffles pages from 1, 2, 3, 4, ... to 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, .... Is there a way to do it? preferably generalized to arbitrary --nup option.

Relevant imagemagick discussion.

I suggest to use package pdfpages directly (at ctan), as pdfjam just abstracts some, not all packages features, for execution in a terminal.
As you don't say anything about the size of the document(s) involved, here's a poor mans example, which works this way, ASSUMING you want 4 pages shown per page:

demo file pdfpgagesNUPrtl.tex contains 4 pages (i.e. a multiple of 4)
file pdfpgagesNUPrtlExcerpt.tex creates what your script would do

pdfpgagesNUPrtl.tex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Demodocument for reordered NUP}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Page 1}
\lipsum[1]
\pagebreak

\section{Page 2}
\lipsum[5-6]
\pagebreak

\section{Page 3}
\lipsum[10-12]
\pagebreak

\section{Page 4}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}

pdfpgagesNUPrtlExcerpt.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[
        pages={2,1,4,3},
        landscape,
        nup=2x2,
        frame=true,
    ]{pdfpagesNUPrtl}
\end{document}


Towards a script
First you need to define how the result shall look like for 1, 2, 3 and 4 pages individually: you may need to adjust the layouts pdfpages uses for missing pages (i.e. too few pages). // Should you have wanted just 2 pages per page, it's still the same: intended layout for 1, 2 (3, 4, 5, etc., i.e. with 1 or 0 missing pages) pages ?
Second you need to know how many pages to print. Worst case you need to pass this number manually to your script.
Third reordering can be achieved in many ways, depending on the sequence you need, e.g. by a simple mapping like:
 1  2  3  4 ... % e.g. as a step or loop function
+1 -1 +1 -1 ... % telling even from odd
 2  1  4  3 ... % just adding

Fourth, implementing such a script can be done in many ways, e.g.:

pdflatex using expl3
lualatex with some functional processing
non-Latex scripting transforming source code directly (.tex to .tex)
etc.

